# how to edit cookbook_file if it is a symlink

Tags: chef-infra, aws-opsworks, cookbook, recipe

I am using AWS Opsworks and I have this cookbook with a recipe that has snippet that will edit the httpd.conf

```
##cookbook file source will check in /files directory
cookbook_file 'apache settings' do 
    action :create #if exists it will update see doc
    source 'httpd.conf'
    path '/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf'
    manage_symlink_source true
end
```

I thought I can edit the file unfortunately not.. after seeing the log , the path `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` is a symlink in the first place. So whenever this recipe runs.. it is overriding into a file. So the `service httpd restart` is broken..

Is there an option so that it can target the file on this symlink and alter its content or is there another way around?

Comment: `manage_symlink_source` shows Chef that it must manage the source file for the symlink. What is the result you are getting? Does Chef create a file in `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` or what?

Comment: it creates the file and replace the symlink and that should be not the case .. I don't want to define the absolute path of httpd.conf , I know it's very complicated to upgrade version but as far I am concerned if there's a way to be dynamic I will find a way.

Comment: I will try something.. If I remember correctly, it was creating the file but the file permission is wrong

Answer (score 0):

Sounds correct on the Chef side, though make sure you are using a new enough version of Chef to support the `manage_symlink_source` property. Better option is to not do this at all. Use the standard community `httpd` cookbook rather than whatever bastardized version Amazon has forked.

Comment: I see unfortunately AWS opsworks requirement is chef 12.0 .. so I have to create my own recipes . Translate linux commands to chef recipes command (so far I have created installing httpd -> php -> php extensions and configuring php.ini)